# GetFireTimeAfter method of ITrigger returning a date which is part of HolidayCalender

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

For existing daily schedule on which I am adding holiday calendar for particular dates for which trigger should not be fired,

Below code is for adding calendar to schedule,

```
    ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(config);
    Instance = sf.GetScheduler();            
    HolidayCalendar cal = new HolidayCalendar();
    cal.AddExcludedDate(new DateTime(2017, 11, 24));
    cal.AddExcludedDate(new DateTime(2017, 11, 25));
    Instance.AddCalendar("Cal", cal, false,true);
```

Now, I am associating this existing calendar with trigger,

```
var trigger1 = Instance.GetTriggersOfJob(new JobKey(jc.Name)).First().GetTriggerBuilder().ModifiedByCalendar("Cal").Build();
```

At last I am printing all the dates on which trigger will be fired,

```
while (startTimeUTC < DateTime.Parse("11-21-2017").AddDays(8))
{
  var nextFireTime = trigger1.GetFireTimeAfter(startTimeUTC);
  Console.WriteLine(" :  " + nextFireTime);
  if (nextFireTime == null) break;
  startTimeUTC = (DateTimeOffset)nextFireTime;
}
```

But in output I am getting dates 24-11-2017 and 25-11-2017 along with other dates. As I have added dates 24-11-2017 and 25-11-2017 as holiday it should not be returned by GetFireTimeAfter() method. 
Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `GetFireTimeAfter` does not check if the returned fire time matches an excluded date from the trigger associated calendar.

An alternate method you can use to list the real fire times, while taking into account a given calendar, is:

```
var fireTimes = TriggerUtils.ComputeFireTimes((IOperableTrigger)trigger1, cal, 30);
```